# How to enable correct code hinting for style.css.erb in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, sublimetext2, erb

Im using a single css file for my Ruby on Rails project. For enabling the asset_path possibility I renamed it to style.css.erb.

Is there a way to make display of the code hinting the right way in Sublime Text 2?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax plugin that lets you write custom rules to detect and apply syntax to files.

Add this to the `syntaxes` key in the user settings for the plugin

```
"syntaxes": [ 
  { "name": "CSS",
    "rules": [
     {"file_name": ".*\\.css.erb$"}
    ]
  }
]
```